# Android Studio's git commit not seeing my modified files

Tags: git, android-studio, settings, android-studio-3.0, git-status

I am more familiar with using git on the command line (MacOS, especially). However, I sometimes try to use the Android Studio VCS "commit", as it is sometimes slightly faster to use. The weird problem that I came across today is that Android's Studio git "commit" does not see my 4 modified files, whereas from the command line, `git status` shows clearly the 4 modified files. I have seen this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183734/i-cant-see-changed-files-on-commit-changes-screen-in-android-studio) and I have checked it is not for any of these reasons (like, not adding the file to the git repository, or it is stashed, etc,). Besides, since `git status` shows the files, they are clearly in the repo, they are not stashed, and they *are* modified.

Here are the screenshots from Android Studio and from the command line showing the discrepancy.
[image: in Android Studio]
[image: in the command line]

Some other things I checked:

1. The project path in Android Studio matches with the path on the command line. (so I'm not looking at a different copy of the git repo)
2. My .gitignore is not excluding those 4 modified files. In any case, even if it is, it should be doing that for both the command line git and the Android Studio git, right?
3. The "path to Git executable" setting in Android Studio is `/usr/bin/git`, same as what I get with `which git` from the command line.

Any ideas what may be the problem?

ps. I may have encountered such a problem before, and just proceeded to use the command line. But this time, I hope to learn something new about the Android Studio git integration :-).

Comment: they were not added. What happens if you tick the boxes in AStudio? Probably is not going to solve the issue by itself, I'm curious

Comment: Nothing happens. Weirdly, Android Studio only sees those 97 unversioned files.

Comment: You called git status from a child folder of your working dir judging by ../.gitignore which is seen by both interfaces. The output is the same if you call status from project root?

Comment: Yes, with the folders suitably changed in the "git status" output, e.g., just showing .gitignore rather than ../.gitignore in the untracked files. Still showing the 4 modified files.

Comment: @DaemonPainter Thanks for your help. I've found the problem in my case, and wrote it below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I had two git roots listed in my Android Studio settings (Preferences->Version Control in MacOS). Not sure how that happened. For this project, my git repo root has two subfolders, and the android project is in one of those two folders. Somehow, Android Studio had added the subfolder with the android project as another git root (see the screenshot with the 2 git roots). Or maybe it was trying to be clever and suggested that I add that subfolder as a git root, and I carelessly clicked "ok".

[image]

So, I removed the git root that pointed to my android project. Then it looks like this,

[image]

And now, git integration in Android Studio is working properly again.

Just in case this happens to anyone else in the future, check your Android Studio git roots (and path to Git executable too, at Preferences->Version Control->Git).